# fmt.Println output does not show up in CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a simple Go Lambda to play with, using the Serverless framework. I expected (as per the documentation) that all output from `fmt.Println` or `log.Println` would show up in Cloudwatch. But I don't see it.

Here's an example of a line I put in purely for testing purposes:

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println("Hello from lambda")

    (...)
```

I'm certain the permissions are correct, because I see the log-group, and there are Cloudwatch entries to view for this lambda. I can actually see the log-group being created in CloudFormation, so I'm sure that's not the issue. But I just don't see the output from any `Println` statements in CloudWatch. This is what I **do** see:

```
START RequestId: fd48461b-3ecd-11e8-9e32-594932db04f2 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: fd48461b-3ecd-11e8-9e32-594932db04f2
REPORT RequestId: fd48461b-3ecd-11e8-9e32-594932db04f2  Duration: 13.82 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

I've tried various other `Print` methods (like `Printf`), but you won't be surprised that didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's embarrassing... Of course, you need to run `make` before running an `sls deploy`... If you don't do that, you'll always be deploying stale code. I'll forgive myself, because it's only my second day at Go, but it's silly all the same.

I have updated my `Makefile` by adding `deploy` and `install`, like so:

```
build:
    dep ensure
    env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/hello hello/main.go
    env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/world world/main.go

deploy:
    sls deploy

install:    build deploy
```

`make install` now builds, then deploys, preventing this issue from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I haven't used Lambda previously. Maybe using glog library is helpful.[see the glog](https://github.com/golang/glog)